# Why is my implementation of strcmp not returning the proper value?

Tags: c++, c

Why is this printing out 0 back in main but 6 when it is inside of the strcmp function?

```
  7 int main()
  8 {
  9 char* str = "test string";
 10 char* str2 = "test strong";
 11 //printf("string length = %d\n",strlen(str));
 12 
 13 int num = strcmp(str,str2);
 14 
 15 printf("num = %d\n",num);
 16 }




 29 int strcmp(char* str, char* str2)
 30 {
 31   if(*str == '\0' && *str2 == '\0')
 32     return 0;
 33   if(*str2 - *str == 0)
 34   {
 35     strcmp(str+1,str2+1);
 36   }
 37   else
 38   {
 39     int num = *str2 - *str;
 40     cout << "num = " <<num<<endl;
 41     return num;
 42     }
 43 }
```

The output is:

num = 6
num = 0

Why is it printing 0 when obviously the value that it should be returning is 6?

Comment: You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to trace the flow of your program, and identify where it goes wrong.

Comment: You're not returning the recursive call.

Comment: I am using print statements.  I have a print statement right before the function returns.  And a print statement right after.  But the values are different.

Comment: Oh okay, I just returned the recursive call, and it worked.  Would you be willing to explain to me what happens when I don't do that?  Why it won't work if I just call the function without returning it?  Shouldn't it still return num?  Thanks

Comment: As a minor note, please note that you can't legally name your function `strcmp()`, the space of functions whose names start with `str` is reserved.

Comment: Haha, yeah that was laziness on my part.  This is purely for a little test, I obviously didn't include <string.h>

Comment: @unwind: Not true. There is no rule reserving `str*` from application use. You may legally name your functions the same as library functions, *unless* you include the standard header that declares that function. It's bad practice, but legal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you forget to add a `return` statement?

```
 33 if(*str2 - *str == 0)
 34   {
 35     return strcmp(str+1,str2+1);
 36   }
```

Otherwise, the code will just skip past the rest of your `if` statement and reach the end of your function, returning nothing (or `0` in your case, but that's being lucky).

Your code will only work if the first characters of both strings are different from each other. Or if both strings are empty.

Your compiler should warn you about this; returning `void` from `non void` function. If not, you should compile with `-Wall` :)

Comment: Not by default :-(  `-Wall` will enable it though. (or explicitly with `-Wreturn-type`)

Comment: @jedwards I always compile with `-Wall` :) thanks! I've updated the answer.

Comment: So what happens when there is no return? Can someone please explain it to me. I think I have some idea but I don't see how it ends up returning 0

Comment: @AvanishGiri I have that in my answer, after your `strcmp` is called it will exit the `if` statement and reach the end of your function.

Comment: Oh, okay.  So does it create a stack, which has a 6 on top and eight 0's on the bottom, and eventually it returns all of these but the last value returned is a 0 and that's what gets finally returned to my main function?  Is that what is going on?  Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @AvanishGiri it recurses just fine if that's what you mean, inside the 8th recursion it does return 6; but subsequently that value is not passed down as the stack unwinds from the 7th recursion back.

Comment: @jedwards: Good compilers (clang) enable a whole lot of warnings by default; and it is actually a test for most new warnings introduced this day: if they cannot be turned on by default on existing software, their value is thoroughly questioned. gcc in its 4.8.0 branch finally managed to improve its diagnosis system to display the proper flag to shut down a warning, so we may hope they start activating some by default.

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
if(*str2 - *str == 0)
{ 
    strcmp(str+1,str2+1); /* no return here. */
}
```

meaning the code will drop through to end, where there is no `return`, which is undefined behaviour:

- From section *6.9.1 Function definitions* of the C99 standard:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

- From section *6.6.3 The return statement* of the C++03 standard:

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

As the behaviour is undefined anything can occur. In this case `0` is returned.

Change to:

```
if(*str2 - *str == 0)
{ 
    return strcmp(str+1,str2+1);
}
```

Comment: So what happens when there is no return?  Can someone please explain it to me.  I think I have some idea but I don't see how it ends up returning 0

Comment: @AvanishGiri, I am pretty sure it is undefined behaviour, checking standard to confirm this...